# What to do with [to-do]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

The [tasks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tasks) tag says -

> Tasks are processes that are to be done. A task can be an item on a
>   **to-do list**, a process that needs to be completed, a scheduled event to
>   take place, or any number of things that need to be accomplished.

But we also have [to-do](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/to-do) tag. As well as a [process](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/process) tag *and* [event](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/events) tag. I know tasks can be different than processes, but as it is defined now it's very unclear. I don't really have a suggestion here.

Comment: The [process] and [event] tags are used predominantly to refer to computer activity.  [Tasks] is pretty mixed between people tasks and computer activity, so it needs to be split up.  The only term I could find with a meaning limited to human task is "chore", but that's not something anybody would think of when tagging.  "To-do" wouldn't cover all of the usage for human tasks, and there are also a number of other closely related tags.  It looks like there's a lot of tag cleanup needed, but no solution to suggest, yet.